# is 1.319 IU/ML Helicobacter Pylori IGG normal?

Tags: diabetes, metabolism, test-results, test, ulcers

Doctor suggested me `H-pylori Stool test` & now I have the report which indicates:

```
Test Name:Helicobacter Pylori IgG
Result:1.319 IU/ML
Normal Ranges: 
< 0.9 --> Negative
0.9-1.0 --> Indeterminated
>=1.1 --> Positive
```

**I want to know is it normal or not?**

Answer (score 2):

Those test results indicate a positive result for traces of Helicobacter pylori in the sample given.

No-one on here will give you any more medical advice. Go see your doctor with those results.